# I'm having trouble trying to design a Class D Amplifier. Does anyone have any tips on where I can start?

Tags: amplifier, filter, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I'm aiming to design a 4 NMOS H-Bridge switching configuration.
I understand that I am going to need:

- two half bridge gate drivers to driver the mosfets
- a comparator stage to compare the audible and high frequency signal
- low pass filter stage to filter the high frequencies.

A few design constraints of this amp includes:

- 5W output
- 42kHz switching frequency
- 2kHz audible signal

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Question seems too broad. Please search the net or [this SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Class+d+MOSFET) to see similar circuits others have designed already. Please [edit] into the question, the sub-circuits you have already found the schematics and design for. Please visit the [tour] page if you have not already done so.

Comment: Try searching for UcD -- "universal class D" (or nCore, but UcD is good enough for you to start with). Best put aside the classical theory when it comes to practise.

Comment: You might want to look into sigma-delta self oscillating class D designs which I've found to be much "simpler" then the triangle wave + comparator method.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to start with the following two tutorials.

The first tutorial is to understand the big picture, the classification of amplifiers.  The second tutorial is to understand the principles, components required, and how to build the real thing.

(1) [Amplifier Classes - Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier-classes.html)

(2) [How to Build a Class-D Power Amp - Cezar Chirila, All About Circuits, 2018apr29](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-build-a-class-d-power-amplifier/)

---

Comment: Thank you for those tutorials. I feel like my understanding on the Class D amplifier has grown more from them.

Comment: @Turei, (1) I glad that you like those tutorials from ET and AAC. Actually I have carefully chosen them from many others not so educational to newbies. (2) Possible errata: the very last line of your question on constraints says "2kHz" audio frequency. I guess you mean "20kHz". (3) The AAC tutorial uses N-channel power MOSFET IRF540N, which is OK but a bit too old. You might like to consider using its newer, logical level trigger replacement ***IRL540N***. Have a great project. Cheers.

Comment: Cool cool thank you. Yeah I was looking at the IRF540N from the tutorial but ended up going with IRF2804 because of the really small Rds(on). How can we see if the H-bridge is switching at our desired switching frequency?